# Will vmstat bi/bo display statistics infor for raw device

Tags: linux

I don't have the required setup to try this so I'll just ask.

`vmstat` will show `bi/bo` for a block device, but will it also be able to show that info for a raw device like some DB partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is looking at the block level, see http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?vmstat. The block size is described there as well.

Telling from my experience you may also be interested in iostat that can give you statistics like this:

```
03/03/11 08:46:33
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.03     1.63    0.06    0.72     0.00     0.01    26.56     0.08  108.28   4.64   0.36
```

I describe it [here](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Iostat), iostat is part of the sysstat package and you can involve it e.g. with the command

```
iostat -xmt 1 -d /dev/sda
```

Also you may be interested in blktrace that can tell you your IO's block sizes. I describe it [here](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Blktrace).

Also you may be interested in benchmark tools like iops, iometer, bonnie and iozone.

Comment: Can you pull the important bits into the A from your site? We try and make the A's here so that they're tolerant to sites going away or links becoming broken. I link to things from my blog too so don't go crazy and pull everything but this is a small snippet. Also you might want to put a reference section at the bottom and give your site more of a referral by including the title of that page etc.